# submit form with large number of checkboxes

Tags: php, html

Whats the best way to submit a form containing large number of **checkboxes**.
no_of_checkboxes is quite big(more than 200).
I need to map the status of checkboxes to a database table in most efficient way.

Comment: Can you give some info on what you've tried, or any issues you're running into?

Comment: What's wrong with just posting the form normally?

Comment: hmm.. perhaps you should be asking yourself why you need to have 200+ checkboxes on a single form.  That sounds like a usability nightmare.

Comment: It's for admin for filling college data which in fact is large.
Posting the form simply seems quite slow.

Comment: Do you have slow internet or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Posting the form simply seems quite slow.

I'm not sure why it is slow, but here is something to try. Put all the checkbox fields outside of the form element so they do not get submitted. Put a hidden element named "boxes" in the form. Use JavaScript to fire a function on submit that json encodes the checkboxes and puts the string in the hidden field "boxes". On the action page, json decode or just save the json string in a single DB field.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var boxes = {};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){

            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                boxes[$(this).prop('name')] = '1';
                //boxes[$(this).prop('name')] = $(this).val(); // if you want the value
            }else{
                boxes[$(this).prop('name')] = '0';
            }
        });
        $('#boxes').val(JSON.stringify(boxes));
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

> I need to map the status of checkboxes to a database table in most
>   efficient way.

```
<?php
$boxes = json_decode($_POST['boxes'], true);
$columns = array();
$values = array();
foreach($boxes as $key=>$val){
  $columns[] = $key;
  $values[] = "'$val'";
}
$columns = "(".implode(', ', $columns).")";
$values = "(".implode(', ', $values).")";
// example query: mysql_query("INSERT INTO table $columns VALUES $values");
?>
```

Comment: I added the part about converting the checkboxes to a json string.